# linking with "local" version of a library

Tags: linker, g++, zlib

Hi I'm trying to install a newversion of zlib, and I dont have root rights, so I'll just install it locally. System install is 1.2.3, and I'm trying to use 1.2.5

I compile like

```
g++ -g myProg.cpp myOs.o -lpthread -IzlibInc/  -LzlibLib/ -lz  -o myProg
```

using ldd it says

```
    ldd myProg
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003c15800000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x0000003c15c00000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000003c17400000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003c15400000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000003c17000000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003c14c00000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003c14800000)
```

So it doesnt link correctly.

Thanks

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////
```

update

I have 2 folders called zlibInc and zlibLib containint the headers and the shared object files.

```
ls zlibLib/
libz.a  libz.so  libz.so.1  libz.so.1.2.5  pkgconfig
ls zlibInc/
zconf.h  zlib.h
```

my sourcecode is

```
cat zlibTest.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <zlib.h>

int main(){
  fprintf(stderr,"%s\n",ZLIB_VERSION);
  int *a=new int[10];

  gzread(stdin,a,5);
  return 0;
}
```

And my command line for compiling is

```
g++ zlibTest.cpp   -I zlibInc/ -L zlibLib/ -L . -I . -lz;ldd a.out
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x0000003c15c00000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000003c17400000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003c15400000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000003c17000000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003c14c00000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003c14800000)
```

Comment: What if you put `-lz` first? Also, you can say `-pthread` as a compiler option, so you don't have to link that manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does link correctly. Local zlib and system-wide zlib have the same SONAME, and run-time linker knows nothing of your local version. You can either supply `-rpath` option to the linker (`-Wl,-rpath=./zlibLib`), or set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable at run-time (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./zlibLib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./myProg`).

Comment: Setting `-rpath` to be relative path is generally not recommended: your program will run differently depending on whether you execute it in a directory that has `./zlibLib/` subdirectory or not. I suggest using `-rpath=${PWD}/zlibLib` instead.